# Convert data in one column to two columns

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns

I have data as seen [here](http://1drv.ms/1SghlwV).

The data is arranged in one column only. Each Unique ID mostly has two sets of data (one or both data sets may be missing) and each entry is separated by tilde (e.g. `~`) character. The sheet also shows the desired output.

Is there a VB code or a sheet formula that can be used to get the desired output? The main document has about 132,300 lines. I haven't come up with a logic.

Answer (score 0):

This should process your data fairly quickly.

```
Sub foo_on_doo_too()
    Dim v As Long, vDOOs As Variant, vRSLTs As Variant

    With ActiveSheet   '<- set this worksheet reference properly!
        vDOOs = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
        ReDim vRSLTs(1 To 2, 1 To Int(UBound(vDOOs, 1) / 4))

        For v = LBound(vDOOs, 1) To UBound(vDOOs, 1) Step 4
            vRSLTs(1, Int(v / 4) + 1) = vDOOs(v, 1)
            vRSLTs(2, Int(v / 4) + 1) = vDOOs(v + 2, 1)
        Next v

        .Cells(4, 3).Resize(UBound(vRSLTs, 2), 2) = _
            Application.Transpose(vRSLTs)
    End With
End Sub
```

Suggest you set the `ActiveSheet` reference to something explicit like `Sheets("Sheet1")`.